# update join with where

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, sql-update

I need to update a certain alert on a loan where the obligor and obligation is something, but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong in the join. This seems to update all alerts in the table rather than the specific one I want. We are using postgresql db

```
update alert set deadline = '08/09/2021'
  from alert as a
 where loan.obligor = 'ALERT-TEST-SIMPLE-DATA-ISSUE'
  join loan on loan.id = a.loan_id
 where obligor = 'ALERT-TEST-SIMPLE-DATA-ISSUE' );
```

Comment: Your code is syntactically incorrect because `loan` is not defined.  You should also be clear about the database you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Workbench usually refers to MySQL.  If so, then the correct syntax is:

```
update alert a join
       loan l
       on l.id = a.loan_id 
    set a.deadline = '2021-08-09'   -- or whatever the date is
    where l.obligor = 'ALERT-TEST-SIMPLE-DATA-ISSUE' ;
```

In Postgres, this would look like:

```
update alert a
    set a.deadline = '2021-08-09'   -- or whatever the date is
    from loan l
    where l.id = a.loan_id  and
          l.obligor = 'ALERT-TEST-SIMPLE-DATA-ISSUE' ;
```

Comment: Sorry think we're actually using postgresql, which I ain't too familiar with. getting ERROR: syntax error at or near "join"
  Position: 16

update alert a join
               ^ on yours

Comment: ERROR: column "a" of relation "alert" does not exist
  Position: 24

    set a.deadline = '08/09/2021'

getting this now

Comment: `s/set a.deadline =/set deadline =/g`

Answer (score -1):

```
update a
set deadline = '08/09/2021' 
from alert as a 
join loan as ll on ll.loan.id = a.loan_id 
where ll.obligor = 'ALERT-TEST-SIMPLE-DATA-ISSUE'
```

I guess you can try the above query

Comment: This looks like microsoft/sybase-syntax.

Comment: definitely it is